# Error reading shapefile with Geopandas in Python

Tags: python, geopandas, parse-error, fiona

I am trying to read a shapefile using geopandas, for which I used `gp.read_file`

```
import geopandas as gp
fl="M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
data=gp.read_file(fl)
```

I am getting the following error:
`TypeError: invalid path: UnparsedPath(path='M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp')`

The traceback to the problem is:

```
----> 1 data=gp.read_file(fl)

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.pyc in read_file(filename, bbox, **kwargs)
     75 
     76     with fiona_env():
---> 77         with reader(path_or_bytes, **kwargs) as features:
     78 
     79             # In a future Fiona release the crs attribute of features will

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\fiona\env.pyc in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    395     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    396         if local._env:
--> 397             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    398         else:
    399             if isinstance(args[0], str):

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.pyc in open(fp, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vfs, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, **kwargs)
    255         if mode in ('a', 'r'):
    256             c = Collection(path, mode, driver=driver, encoding=encoding,
--> 257                            layer=layer, enabled_drivers=enabled_drivers, **kwargs)
    258         elif mode == 'w':
    259             if schema:

c:\python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\fiona\collection.pyc in __init__(self, path, mode, driver, schema, crs, encoding, layer, vsi, archive, enabled_drivers, crs_wkt, ignore_fields, ignore_geometry, **kwargs)
     54 
     55         if not isinstance(path, (string_types, Path)):
---> 56             raise TypeError("invalid path: %r" % path)
     57         if not isinstance(mode, string_types) or mode not in ('r', 'w', 'a'):
     58             raise TypeError("invalid mode: %r" % mode)

TypeError: invalid path: UnparsedPath(path='M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp')
```

There is some problem with fiona I guess but I do not have much idea about.
I have installed `fiona 1.8.6` and `geopandas 0.5.0` version installed in my system. I am using python 2.7

Comment: Does the drive letter `M:` refers to a shared folder on a local network?

Comment: `M:` here is due to an external hard drive

Answer (score 0):

It says that path is invalid. I would try to replace comma in your path:

before:

```
fl="M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions,shp"
```

after:

```
fl="M:/rathore/vic_5km/L2_data/L2_data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
```

Comment: The comma was a typing error, I have edited the question. The same error still there

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with version of fiona and geopandas. Can you find the path of the file through your command prompt/terminal and use the same for reading the file
like below

```
fl="/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Data/DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How do I get file path in UNC?

Answer (score 0):

First, `isinstance(your_path, ((str,), Path))` is evaluated to `False` in `fiona\collection.pyc`, which is strange.

Also, [those lines in fiona/**init**.py](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/0fd1e297c85a0462b35ed8b44c578528d6741739/fiona/__init__.py#L240y) module should take care of the case where your path is a `pathlib.Path` object, but it apparently don't... I'm not sure, it may be an issue with fiona.

I still think the problem come from the [parse_path(path)](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/blob/master/fiona/path.py) method of fiona.

Here are some things you should try:

1. If `M:` is a shared folder on a local network, try replacing 'M:/...' by the UNC path (ex: "//local/folder/path/to/file")
2. If you use an IDE (like Pycharm, Eclipse or VsCode), add a breakpoint on your third line, use the debugger and go deep down until you reach the `parse_data` method. then look at what your path looks. If you don't use an IDE, consider to install one...
3. If you can, try copying the shapefile on the same drive that your python script, and check if the errors still raises.

Comment: Hi, I do not know how to get a file path in unc but I copied the shapefile in the same drive but the same error still there: `TypeError: invalid path: ParsedPath(path='DAMSELFISH_distributions.shp', archive=None, scheme=None)`

Comment: I think you should create an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) of geopandas, cause it's really weird...

Comment: I did but nobody responded there